# Using MAMP and Ruby on Rails, do I need two separate MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mamp, osx-elcapitan

I've searched about this and all I can find are articles from 3-4 years ago, so I feel sorry for asking this again but I guess a lot of things have changed since then.

I'm using MAMP on OSX 10.11 but I also want to use RoR, I've installed ruby using Rbenv and have also installed rails gem. Right know I need to install MySQL but I don´t know if I should install it from scratch using brew or what should be the best way to use both MAMP and ROR.

Comment: You can reuse an existing MySQL instance, you just have to point Rails at it. Articles 3-4 years old would still be usable information.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using the MAMP MySQL. You can get the connection details from the MySQL tab in MAMP. But you might want to try [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) instead. You don't need all that Apache and PHP junk running...

Comment: The reason you might only be finding old articles on Rails + PHP is that no-one really uses Rails with MySQL anymore. The only benefit of MySQL is that happens to be running on web hotells everywhere, and you don't deploy rails to web hotells...

Comment: So you think the best 'environment' I could have is PHP+MySQL on one side and Rails + PostgreSQL on the other one?